# AngularJS: how to access the topmost scope without navigating via multiple $parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I know there is a lot of question on this, but i couldn't find my answer in them.
I have a directive for my popups that have many templates,

HTML

```
<popup template="popupTemplate"></popup>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('popup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      template: '='
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      // do something on $scope.template
    }
  }
});
```

now on another element I define the name of template for the target popup

```
<button popup-template="upload-avatar"></button>
```

directive

```
app.directive('popupTemplate', function () {
  return {
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.bind('click', function () {
        $scope.$parent.popupTemplate = $attrs.popupTemplate;
        $scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**the problem:**
when I'm clicking on an element inside a nested directive. cause I need to deal with:

```
$scope.$parent.popupTemplate
$scope.$parent.$parent.popupTemplate
```

It's not a good idea. **I need to know how to access to first parent scope with a unique syntax instead of multiple $parent.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap `popupTemplate`:

```
<popup template="whatever.popupTemplate"></popup>
```

Then u can:

```
$scope.whatever.popupTemplate = $attrs.popupTemplate;
```

Without $parent at all.

Lets say u have parent scope A and child B. By default B copies all values from A. Copies here means coping pointer.

Compare in java:

```
void bad(String s) {
    s = "new";
}

void good(String[] s) {
    s[0] = "new";
}
```

Comment: Worked! thank you. but may you explain what's the difference of $scope.popup.template and $scope.popupTemplate?